# Symmetries of a square compositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

For my abstract algebra class, we were to try and answer a few compositions based on the symmetries of a square. For our purposes, these compositions always go from right to left.

So, Rot3 was to be composed with M3.

Rot3 is equal to 1234 with its second row of 4123. For M3, its second row is 1432.

I'm getting an answer of 4321 (M2), but my teacher says the answer should be 2143 (M1). I just am not getting that. Please help.

Comment: Unfortunately, just saying "compositions go right to left" doesn't always clear up the issue. You need to clarify with your instructor exactly which symmetry is applied first, and which is applied second. If the rotation (what you call $Rot_3$) is applied first, your teacher is correct-if the reflection (what you call $M_3$) is applied first, you are correct.

Comment: She says that compositions always go from right to left, and yet a friend pointed out to me that when the composition symbol is present, the operation goes from left to right. I have no idea why she said that those examples are "right to left." That doesn't seem correct at all.

Comment: Normally, when we write $f \circ g$, what we mean is we apply $g$ *first* and then $f$, so $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. However sometimes (and especially in studying algebra) the order of composition is reversed (the argument is then typically written on the left), and we have $(x)(f \circ g) = ((x)f)g$. As we typically read "left to right", composition (as it is usually understood, like in say, Calculus) is a bit weird in that it is in the opposite order of how we *read* it, and algebraists sometimes prefer algebraic functions "act on the right".